# Calculating number of ratings needed to reach 4 stars?

Tags: analysis, logic, self-learning

So, a company have 500 reviews and their current rating is 3.2 stars out of 5.

I'm trying to calculate how many 5 star reviews they'd need to get to reach an overall rating of 4 stars.

I'm basically just looking for an equation that would output this answer (using to track stuff in a spreadsheet).

Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: we need to know the means by which they compute the overall rating. for example, is it an average?

Comment: Yes, the overall rating is the average of all the reviews.

Comment: if you're satisfied with your answer, then please click the green check to close the post. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An equation would look something like...

$$n = \frac{t(m_2 - m_1)}{c - m_2}$$

where

$m_1$ is the old average among $t$ number of ratings

$m_2$ is the new average among $t$ number of ratings

$t$ is the number of ratings used in the first average

$c$ is the score ($0-5$ stars) of the additional ratings used in the new average

$n$ is the number of the additional ratings used in the new average

---

In your specific application you have...

$$n = \frac{500(4 - 3.2)}{5-4}$$

You can see the math as follows: let $s_i$ be the $i$th score, or rating, for $i = 1,2,3,...,500$. We know that...

$$\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{500} s_i}{500} = 3.2$$

$$\sum_{i=1}^{500} s_i = 1600$$

We want to solve for $n$ in the following

$$\frac{5n+ \sum_{i=1}^{500} s_i}{500 +n} = 4$$

$$\frac{5n+ 1600}{500 +n} = 4$$

$$5n+ 1600 = 4(500 +n)$$

$$5n+ 1600 = 2000 + 4n$$

$$5n - 4n = 2000 - 1600$$

$$n = 400$$

Comment: Hmm now I just have to figure out how to make this work in Google Sheets lol